# Jquery counting

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, count

How do i count #total value + 170 with jquery?

```
$("#member").click(function() {
if ($('#member').is(':checked')) {
    var totalv = $("#total").val();
    var skatz = 170;
    var skaits = totalv + skatz;
    $("#total").val(skaits);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the provided value is actually a number (You can do onkeypress or keyup each time but I say you should always check on submission). Below is your code modified to work (With checks to see if the value is a number).

EDIT: Make sure that your javascript has document ready wrapped around it. (Functions can be outside of this call)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#member").click(function() {
    if ($('#member').is(':checked')) {
        var totalv = $("#total").val();
        if(isNumber(totalv) == true)
        {
            var skatz = 170;
            var skaits = parseInt(totalv) + skatz;
            $("#total").val(skaits);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You must enter a numerical value");
        }
    }
});

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: Even if the input is masked, a user could still make modifications in other ways, or there could be something you have forgotten (I'm not saying you have). I always have submission checking even with masks myself, I consider it good practice :)

Answer (score 1):

The result of `.val()` will be a string, so you first need to convert it to a number:

```
var totalv = $("#total").val();
var skatz = 170;
var skaits = +totalv + skatz;
$("#total").val(skaits);
```

(notice the additional + prefix to the totalv variable.